# Mango tree leaves are getting tiny brown (like dryed out) on the edges

Tags: leaves, soil, mango

Mango tree leaves are getting tiny brown (like dried out) on the edges. I attach photos to see better, and also a photo of the soil.

Like in this picture,
tiny bits of brown:
[image]

Same here: [image]

How soil looks: [image]